# setState value is not preserved between animation frames

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small snake game where the counter is updated from another component X. I am subscribing to this event in component Y. When the game is ended I want to send data to the backend to store it. Unfortunately the score value that I get from the `useState` is not preserved and I'm always sending 0. I have deployed a game to the heroku which has all source code available. Here is the link: https://best-snake.herokuapp.com/game

Main page of interest webpack://game/src/pages/GamePage/GamePage.tsx

Perhaps there is something easy, but I cannot see it myself.